# HTML code conversion to PHP and merge with html

Tags: php, html

I need help for this conversion of HTML to PHP 
This is my code and I want to write inside the if tag with echo to get the results of the base of conditions for more info I am getting the error around the value of the input field from the database.

```
   <td>
       <input type="text" name="sale_rate[]" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)" id="sale_rate_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $val['sale_rate'] ?>">

       <input type="hidden" name="sale_rate_value[]" id="sale_rate_value_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
   </td>
```

to like this

```
 <?php  if($user_id == 1) 
     echo "<td><input type="text" name="sale_rate[]" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)" id="sale_rate_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $val['sale_rate'] ?>">

             <input type="hidden" name="sale_rate_value[]" id="sale_rate_value_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">

            </td>";
 ?>
```

Any kindly of help will be so appreciated

Comment: Don't nest `<?phph ?>` tags inside one another! (`<?php echo $x; ?>`)

Comment: yeah i know this, but my main focus is to get the value from the database according to conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can close and reopen `<?php ?>` tags. So you don't need `echo`

```
 <?php  if($user_id == 1){ ?> 
    <td>
       <input type="text" name="sale_rate[]" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)" id="sale_rate_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $val['sale_rate'] ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="sale_rate_value[]" id="sale_rate_value_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">    
     </td>
 <?php } ?>
```

Alternatively, you can use `if/endif` syntax:

```
<?php if($statement): ?>
   <some-html>...</some-html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches, which amount to as much a matter of style as anything else.

Personally, I prefer to not have numerous instances of `<?php [CODE HERE] ?>` throughout my markup, so, instead, I would favour something more like this:

```
<?php

  if($user_id == 1) {

    echo '
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="sale_rate[]" onchange="getProductData('.$x.')" id="sale_rate_'.$x.'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="'.$val['sale_rate'].'">
        <input type="hidden" name="sale_rate_value[]" id="sale_rate_value_'.$x.'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
    ';
  }
?>
```